# How can I check the validity of each IP in a list?

Tags: ip

The list formatting looks like this:

> 1.127.16.0
>
> 1.127.16.8
>
> 1.127.16.22
>
> 1.127.16.0

and it goes on for ~20,000 IP's. I would imagine I need to do something like a mass ping. Could I get any hints? I would like to use Lua/C++/Python if a script is necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by _validity_?

Comment: If it is a real IP address.

Comment: A real IP address is four groups of numbers 0-255, is that what you really want?

Comment: I know but for example the whole 255 range has not even been given out yet, and some are restricted.

Comment: @user2423308 Nevertheless, even the `255` ones (which have a special purpose) are real ones. Define what you really mean with "valid" and act appropriately. For example, there are lists of IP address ranges such as http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xml where you can evaluate which meaning your given IP address really has.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip = "192.168.0.1";

if(!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
  echo "IP is not valid";
}else{
  echo "IP is valid";
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_ip.asp